# Set Jackson DeserializationContext Attribute in per-request, thread-safe manner

Tags: web-services, jackson, thread-safety, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm looking to be able to add a request-scoped attribute (a JAX-RS [`ContainerRequestContext`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) because I would rather use Jackson to convert my parameters to objects than JAX-RS's ill conceived and clunky `ParameterConverterProviders`) to a `DeserializationContext` so that it can be obtained from within a `JsonDeserializer`.  I must call `convertValue()` rather than simply `readValue()` (not dealing with actual JSON) so I am not able to create an `ObjectReader` in each thread unless I am willing to serialize my map to a JSON string first and then read it back -which would be incredibly inefficient.

I'd like to be able to do something that accomplishes the following but in a per request manner:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

//in request-scoped context:
om.getDeserializationContext().setAttribute("requestContext",containerRequestContext)
Map<String,Object> mapOfRequestParameters = ...

BeanOfVastImportance bean = om.convertValue(mapOfRequestParameters,BeanOfVastImportance.class)
```

How can I achieve this without the massive, superfluous overhead of needing to create a new ObjectMapper for each individual request thread?

Comment: Configuring the mapper is not safe. Can you just create a certain number of mappers base on all possible configurations and just do a lookup for the one you need?

Comment: That is technically feasible, but would basically eradicate the convenience of Jackson. I really just need to be able to call convertValue on an immutable ObjectReader (where it is possible to set context attributes), - but that is not possible at the moment, so looking or a solution that would allow me to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

This may be achieved with:

```java
objectMapper.reader().forType(Request.class)
    .withAttribute("key", "value").readValue<Request>("source")
```

Comment: +1.  There is some overhead in that a new ObjectReader is created, but it retains the same references except for the ones you are customizing so it has a rather small footprint, and since it is bound to the request it's lifetime is very short lived.  If the context you are trying to pass is specific to each request this looks like the right solution.