# CDI (Quarkus) injection in JsonSerializer

Tags: java, jackson, quarkus

Suppose I have an object that I would like to serialize:

```java
class ToSerialize {
  @JsonSerialize(using = ThingSerializer.class)
  public Thing thing;
}
```

where

```java
public class ThingSerializer extends StdSerializer<Thing> {

    protected ThingSerializer() {
        super(Thing.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Thing thing, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        // Some implementation
    }
}
```

How can I inject stuff into `ThingSerializer` without having to resort to static access to `CDI.current()`? Something like:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ThingSerializer extends StdSerializer<Thing> {

    @Inject
    SomeService someService;

    protected ThingSerializer() {
        super(Thing.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Thing thing, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        // Some implementation
    }
}
```

which, unfortunately, doesn't seem to work.

I know I can use a `ObjectMapperCustomizer` to add a new `ThingSerializer` globally, to which I can pass any dependency I need. However, I really want to avoid having to register this `ThingSerializer` globally, because the default serialization mechanism is fine 99% of the time.

I also know I can pass CDI beans as attributes to the `ObjectMapper` which I can access in my `ThingSerializer`, but I'm hoping for a slightly more elegant approach. Is there such an approach?

Comment: Not an expert in quarkus, but it seems like you have to "invent" some static methods to provide access to the services, as the jackson serialisers are managed by jackson only

Answer (score 2):

Register your serializer via [ObjectMapperCustomizer](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#jackson) and resolve dependencies during registration.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.quarkus.jackson.ObjectMapperCustomizer;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {
    @Inject
    SomeService someService;

    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        var module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Thing.class, new ThingSerializer(someService));
        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. If I am not mistaken, with this approach all Thing-instances will be serialized with the ThingSerializer, instead of just the one on ToSerialize. Is there any way to avoid that? This is what I meant with “ I know I can use a ObjectMapperCustomizer to add a new ThingSerializer globally, to which I can pass any dependency I need. However, I really want to avoid having to register this ThingSerializer globally, because the default serialization mechanism is fine 99% of the time.”

Comment: You can use "per-call attributes" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756939/set-jackson-deserializationcontext-attribute-in-per-request-thread-safe-manner) and extract `SomeService` from `serializerProvider` or just extract bean using static `CDI.current().getBeanManager()`